# Getting key error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I am now trying to display the information I got using Describe. For some reason, I keep getting error message saying `Key error: 'pixelType.'`. I have no idea why this gives me the error because this is exactly how it is worded in ArcGIS help website. Could someone please tell me what is wrong?

```
def data_report(workspace):

elements = defaultdict(list)

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, topdown=True)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for dirname in dirnames:  # 'FeatureDataset'
        desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, dirname))
        elements[desc['dataType']].append(desc)

    for filename in filenames:
        desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
        elements[desc['dataType']].append(desc)  

report = []

for element_type, element_list in elements.items():
    report += [f"{element_type}:"]
    for element_description in element_list:



if element_type == "RasterDataset":    
    report +=  [f"\t\t{element_description['name']}"]
    report +=  [f"\t\t\t\tThe number of band: {element_description['bandCount']}"]
    report +=  [f"\t\t\t\tThe format: {element_description['format']}"]
    report +=  [f"\t\t\t\tPixel type: {element_description['pixelType']}"]
```

Comment: I got the whole code, but I was told once not to post my entire code. But if it is necessary, I can post it.

Comment: Ok, I added more code. Thank you.

Comment: But then I do not know why everything else is displayed. The name, bandCount, and other properties are displayed on the screen when I run this code, but only pixel type gives me the error.

Comment: Your indentation is off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the documentation for the [Describe Raster Dataset](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/raster-dataset-properties.htm).

There is no `pixelType` property there.  However, as you can see at the top of the documentation, it can also include the properties for Raster Band **ONLY IF** the raster is a single-band raster.

Here's the documentation for the [Describe Raster Band](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/raster-band-properties.htm).  As you can see, a Raster Band, and hence a **single-band raster dataset** would have a pixelType property.

So you must test if it is a single band raster before requesting this property.  OR, test to see if the property exists before attempting to read it.

So, you could change the last part of your code to:

```
if element_type == "RasterDataset":    
    report +=  [f"\t\t{element_description['name']}"]
    report +=  [f"\t\t\t\tThe number of band: {element_description['bandCount']}"]
    report +=  [f"\t\t\t\tThe format: {element_description['format']}"]
    if 'pixelType' in element_description:
        report +=  [f"\t\t\t\tPixel type: {element_description['pixelType']}"]
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case I've found it simpler and safer to use the [children property of the describe object](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q30000001w000000):

```
if element_type == "RasterDataset":
    InRas = arcpy.Raster(element_description['catalogPath']) # make a raster object
    Desc  = arcpy.Describe(InRas)
    PxType= Desc.children[0].pixelType

InRas=arcpy.Raster(r'C:\PATH\TO\RASTER\Raster3band.png')
Desc = arcpy.Describe(InRas)
print('Raster has {} bands with a pixel type of {}'.format(Desc.bandCount,Desc.children[0].pixelType))
```

returns *Raster has 3 bands with a pixel type of U8*

```
InRas=arcpy.Raster(r'C:\PATH\TO\RASTER\RasterSingleBand.img')
Desc = arcpy.Describe(InRas)
print('Raster has {} bands with a pixel type of {}'.format(Desc.bandCount,Desc.children[0].pixelType))
InRas = None # free the python object to free up resources not the dataset
```

returns *Raster has 1 bands with a pixel type of F32*

But first cast your path string to a [Raster object](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000051000000) before describing, I have found that some raster formats have issues being described directly, the Raster object causes less issues when described; commonly the bands can be acessed by `element_description['catalogPath'] + r'\band_1'` but in some instances band_1 is named Red, just to make life difficult, grabbing the first child is safer to get the properties of the first (and second, and third etc) band irrespective of the band naming.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I make that "print" part into "report +=" ? I need to add the result to the report

Comment: I use string.format to pack up multiple variables. I find it easier to re-read later as the format string contains the layout with {} placemarkers = a shorter format string, then have a variable for each of your properties, then pack them all up to a list. What's up with all the tabs? What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: In my initial post, I have a report = [], and once I extract all these information, I am writing them onto the report using   report += . I think your code simply just prints the results, but I need them to be written on the report first, and then I am printing the report.

Comment: The question is about *pixelType* as a property of a raster, thus the answer is about getting the pixelType from a raster; I cannot understand what you're trying to do with your objects when you have them therefore I can't help integrate the value of the pixelType into your code - a question about that sort of thing needs to be posted on Stack Overflow as there would no longer be a GIS component.